# Get content of page using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to use PHP's cURL to visit a page on an external site, and get some the whole html content of the page.

When i visit the site, it will redirect me to another page on the same site. Also, i have to set the useragent, i want a useragent for PC windows7 chrome and iPhone 4s. This is what i got so far:

```
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER , true)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$kl = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $kl;
```

**Notice:**
I will probably run into more errors.

Comment: use simplehtmldom or phpquery to parse the html

Comment: @DevZer0 these libs had been designed for PHP4. in PHP5 there is `DOMXPath` or `simple_xml_element->xpath()`

Comment: i want to use cURL. But thanks for the comments

Comment: @ahmadalbayati cURL will not let you manipulate the html.

Comment: I Want to get HTML Values from the source, can't i do that with cURL?

Comment: you can get html result, but if you want to manipulate the html, get some items inside it, you should write more code to analyze it. "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" it is helpful.And if there is a redirection, you should use **curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);** to follow it

Comment: @hek2mgl, No, actually BOTH libraries require PHP5.  The nice feature is the ability to use jquery-like selectors (and also, at least simplehtmldom, is very tolerant with poor written html)

Comment: @chris Again, use DOMXPath. It's much faster as it is natice c code. and in fact: jquery is like xpath, not vise versa. so why not using the original? ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl Oh my comment wasn't in the sense of "simplehtmldom is better than domxpath", it was more like a response because you said that both simplehtmldom and phpquery were designed for php4, while actually are php5 libraries. And also added they did have an extra benefit. But if DOMXPath can do the same job as simple html dom parser, but faster, then I guess that is the way to go ^_^

Comment: @chris I thought you are the OP.. Now I see your comment in a different light. However, I'll not stop telling people that PHP5 has `DOMXPath` what is much faster - because native C code - than that simplehtmldom library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So:

1. Search the proper UserAgent strings on the 'net.
2. Enable `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` as @TroyCheng indicated
3. Enable the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` & `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.

Comment: thanks. it did it. sadly i can't give you the bounty until 23 hours have past :/

Answer (score 7):

You might also need to consider urls with https

```
$cookie = tmpfile();
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31' ;

$ch = curl_init($url);

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20 , 
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie ,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0 ,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$kl = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $kl;
```

Comment: Thanks, it also did it, and +1 for putting it into array :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a library like [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz) ?

```
$request = new Buzz\Message\Request('GET', '/', 'http://google.com');
$response = new Buzz\Message\Response();

$client = new Buzz\Client\Curl();
// do not check https validity
$client->setVerifyPeer(false);
// define your user agent
$client->setOption('CURLOPT_USERAGENT', $userAgent);
$client->setOption('CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE', true);
$client->setOption('CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR', true);
$client->send($request, $response);

if ($response->isOk())
{
  echo $response->getContent();

  // or if you want the dom
  echo $response->toDomDocument();
}
```